PHP Composer errors with XDEBUG_MODE not recognized in VS Code
I am running VS Code.  I have PHP installed locally, Composer installed locally and the VS Code Composer plugin installed in VS Code.  From VS Code terminal, I pulled the GitHub master project and the pr/#XX that I am trying to clean up and merge
I made all my changes to my project repo branch and am now trying to test it, from the VS Code Terminal I ran the following:
composer install - downloads/installs all the required php files and packages
composer update - updates most of all the installed packages
composer test - on the project and it fails with:

XDEBUG_MODE=coverage vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.dist.xml
'XDEBUG_MODE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Through much reading, I added both to my php.ini file:
xdebug.mode=coverage
XDEBUG_MODE=coverage

What is happening and how can I fix this?

I found some docs on Xdebug here and cloned the xdebug.git (https://xdebug.org/docs/install#windows), then supplied my phpinfo() output to get the right downloaded php_xdebug.dll file to my php/ext folder and then added zend_extension = xdebug.
I verified Xdebug is enabled from CLI with: php -v
PHP 8.3.11 (cli) (built: Aug 27 2024 21:28:59) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.11, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2024, by Derick Rethans

I closed and restarted VS Code, but the composer test problem still persists.
I also removed the two xdebug_mode lines (above) from my php.ini file, to no effect.

How is this problem related to Composer itself? As far as I see, it's the command calling PHPUnit that throws this error. Running Composer with XDebug enabled should not be neccessary anywhere. Also, are you probably running this on Windows? Prepending XDEBUG_MODE=coverage looks more like a Unix thing to me

You can add custom commands to Composer and I think that's what test is. Find your main composer.json file, look for a "scripts" key and update the question with that information. It looks like you have a custom command that's only been tested on Linux. As quick workaround, you can run tests directly rather than through Composer.

I am just getting started with this type of project for the first time.  I have never run VS Code or composer before so I am unfamiliar with the environments and necessary steps and to a certain degree have struggled just to get this far.  But thank you @ÁlvaroGonzález and NicoHase because both your comments led me to fix the issue.  It was a Windows (php.ini) xdebug.mode vs Linux XDEBUG_MODE setting INSIDE of composer.json - so both tips helped me fix it.  Thank you.


"Through much reading, I added both to my php.ini file:"  The XDEBUG_MODE=coverage is an environment variable. It does nothing in php.ini.


@LazyOne - I managed to fix it


XDEBUG_MODE=coverage vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.dist.xml -- this looks like a Linux/MacOS style command (where you can set the env variable XDEBUG_MODE=coverage in the same line before the actual command that gets executed. And you are on Windows.  So from what I see -- your composer test (in its current form) is not suitable for running on Windows.


composer script has a feature to set envitonment variables regardless of platform. reading the scripts section in the docs may prevent some headaches.

Composer scripts cross-platform compatible environment variable setting (ref):
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": [
            "@putenv XDEBUG_MODE=coverage",
            "vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.dist.xml"
         ]
    }
}


For anyone who has similar issues I was able to fix this AFTER installing XDebug locally on my Windows computer.
Specifically, in the composer.json file:
I changed:
// a Linux variable setting
"scripts": {
    "test": ["XDEBUG_MODE=coverage vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.dist.xml"]
},

To:
"scripts": {
    "test": ["vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.dist.xml"]
},

And in my Windows php.ini file I had to set:
xdebug.mode=coverage
And then for notes purposes, I also added the following so others developers will know how the test works in each environment:
"scripts-descriptions": {
    "test" : "Set PHP.ini xdebug.mode=coverage (windows) OR set 'test':['XMODE_DEBUG=coverage vendor/bin/phpunit ...'] (linux)"
}

Credit to both @AlvaroGonzalez and @NicoHase for pointing me in the right direction.

"OR set 'test':['XMODE_DEBUG=coverage vendor/bin/phpunit ...'] (linux)"
}" If they need to edit the task just because they are on another OS .. then your solution is not that good. If you cannot solve the issue in OS-independent way (e.g. you should be able to specify env vars like XDEBUG_MODE=coverage in the actual PHPUnit config file), then it makes sense to have a separate command for Windows OS (e.g. test-win)

Thankks.  I was wondering about that and saw the section for composer env variables.  I will look into it to get it corrected.
